# A lot of WriteConflict errors with MongoDB transactions

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose, transactions

I'm currently playing with transactions in latest available docker image of MongoDB 4.1.4 (using Node 8.12.0 and Mongoose 5.3.8 as client). I've made a simple replica set with 3 mongo instances, everything works fine and all until I do a lot of `WriteConflict` errors during short time.

My code looks like this:

```
// name, value are strings
// date is current time

const session = await createAnalyticsTransaction(); // returns 'session'

// _id is pregenerated
var stat = await Logger.findById(_id).session(session);

if (stat) {
    // do nothing if it already exists
    return true;
} 

await Logger.update({
    _id
}, {
    $setOnInsert: {
        _id,
        name,
        created: date.toDate(),
        modified: date.toDate()
    }
}, { 
    session, 
    upsert: true 
});

/*
    var period = 'month';
    var time = '2018-11'; 
    await Analytics.update({
        _id
    }, { 
        $setOnInsert: {
            _id,
            name,
            period,
            time,
            created: date.toDate()
        },
        $inc: inc
    }, {
        upsert: true,
        session: session 
    });
*/

await session.commitTransaction();
await session.endSession();
```

Everything works here so far until I uncomment an upsert into Analytics collection with `$inc` and `$setOnInsert` and run about 1000 simultaneous operations. The idea is that Analytics collection should be created if it wasn't created yet. And then I start getting a lot of `MongoError: WriteConflict`, with error's property `errorLabels` having `TransientTransactionError`.

[image]

I assume it's because of `$inc` or `upsert: true`? Did anyone experience this? What's the best solution in this case?

```
{ MongoError: WriteConflict
   at /Users/akuzmenok/Zend/MeteorLingua/lingua-analytics/node_modules/mongodb-core/lib/connection/pool.js:581:63
   at authenticateStragglers (/Users/akuzmenok/Zend/MeteorLingua/lingua-analytics/node_modules/mongodb-core/lib/connection/pool.js:504:16)
   at Connection.messageHandler (/Users/akuzmenok/Zend/MeteorLingua/lingua-analytics/node_modules/mongodb-core/lib/connection/pool.js:540:5)
   at emitMessageHandler (/Users/akuzmenok/Zend/MeteorLingua/lingua-analytics/node_modules/mongodb-core/lib/connection/connection.js:310:10)
   at Socket.<anonymous> (/Users/akuzmenok/Zend/MeteorLingua/lingua-analytics/node_modules/mongodb-core/lib/connection/connection.js:453:17)
   at emitOne (events.js:116:13)
   at Socket.emit (events.js:211:7)
   at addChunk (_stream_readable.js:263:12)
   at readableAddChunk (_stream_readable.js:250:11)
   at Socket.Readable.push (_stream_readable.js:208:10)
   at TCP.onread (net.js:597:20)
=> awaited here:
   at Function.Promise.await (/Users/akuzmenok/.meteor/packages/promise/.0.11.1.1ugu6ow.mjjhg++os+web.browser+web.browser.legacy+web.cordova/npm/node_modules/meteor-promise/promise_server.js:56:12)
   at Promise.asyncApply (imports/lib/analytics.js:97:9)
   at /Users/akuzmenok/.meteor/packages/promise/.0.11.1.1ugu6ow.mjjhg++os+web.browser+web.browser.legacy+web.cordova/npm/node_modules/meteor-promise/fiber_pool.js:43:40
=> awaited here:
   at Function.Promise.await (/Users/akuzmenok/.meteor/packages/promise/.0.11.1.1ugu6ow.mjjhg++os+web.browser+web.browser.legacy+web.cordova/npm/node_modules/meteor-promise/promise_server.js:56:12)
   at Promise.asyncApply (imports/lib/analytics.js:139:5)
   at /Users/akuzmenok/.meteor/packages/promise/.0.11.1.1ugu6ow.mjjhg++os+web.browser+web.browser.legacy+web.cordova/npm/node_modules/meteor-promise/fiber_pool.js:43:40
=> awaited here:
   at Function.Promise.await (/Users/akuzmenok/.meteor/packages/promise/.0.11.1.1ugu6ow.mjjhg++os+web.browser+web.browser.legacy+web.cordova/npm/node_modules/meteor-promise/promise_server.js:56:12)
   at Promise.asyncApply (imports/lib/analytics.js:158:5)
   at /Users/akuzmenok/.meteor/packages/promise/.0.11.1.1ugu6ow.mjjhg++os+web.browser+web.browser.legacy+web.cordova/npm/node_modules/meteor-promise/fiber_pool.js:43:40
=> awaited here:
   at Function.Promise.await (/Users/akuzmenok/.meteor/packages/promise/.0.11.1.1ugu6ow.mjjhg++os+web.browser+web.browser.legacy+web.cordova/npm/node_modules/meteor-promise/promise_server.js:56:12)
   at Promise.asyncApply (imports/lib/analytics.js:49:23)
   at /Users/akuzmenok/.meteor/packages/promise/.0.11.1.1ugu6ow.mjjhg++os+web.browser+web.browser.legacy+web.cordova/npm/node_modules/meteor-promise/fiber_pool.js:43:40
=> awaited here:
   at Function.Promise.await (/Users/akuzmenok/.meteor/packages/promise/.0.11.1.1ugu6ow.mjjhg++os+web.browser+web.browser.legacy+web.cordova/npm/node_modules/meteor-promise/promise_server.js:56:12)
   at Promise.asyncApply (imports/lib/analytics.js:14:23)
   at /Users/akuzmenok/.meteor/packages/promise/.0.11.1.1ugu6ow.mjjhg++os+web.browser+web.browser.legacy+web.cordova/npm/node_modules/meteor-promise/fiber_pool.js:43:40
 errorLabels: [ 'TransientTransactionError' ],
 operationTime: Timestamp { _bsontype: 'Timestamp', low_: 12, high_: 1541424838 },
 ok: 0,
 errmsg: 'WriteConflict',
 code: 112,
 codeName: 'WriteConflict',
 '$clusterTime':
  { clusterTime: Timestamp { _bsontype: 'Timestamp', low_: 12, high_: 1541424838 },
    signature: { hash: [Object], keyId: 0 } },
 name: 'MongoError',
 [Symbol(mongoErrorContextSymbol)]: {} }
```

Another note, I'm starting a transaction like this:

```
const session = await MongoAnalytics.startSession({ causalConsistency: true });
session.startTransaction({ readConcern: { level: 'snapshot' }, writeConcern: { w: 'majority' } });
```

Comment: Could you post the error as a text? The image is not searchable and I can't find anything like 'WriteConcern' visually.

Comment: @AlexBlex just added the full error message

Comment: Ok, so it's not a 'WriteConcern' but a 'WriteConflict'. You may want to update the title and the question to avoid confusion.

Comment: The conflict comes from concurrent updates of the same document. Since you wrapped it in transaction, individual writes are not retryable - you need to retry whole transaction. There are some examples in the docs: https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/transactions/#retry-transaction

Comment: @AlexBlex is there any row-level lock available? I'm searching for a nicer solution than retrying

Comment: It is always a "row level lock" - operations are atomic on document level https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/read-isolation-consistency-recency/ and mongo handles it transparently. In fact it has different locks: https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/faq/concurrency/ . The thing is you are asking for "multi-table lock" starting a multi-document transaction. The nicer solution is what Gregory mentioned - rethink you architecture to avoid transactions if possible.

Answer (score 11):

You read data from database and then update it. It look like :

```
DATA (state 0) <---
UPDATED DATA (state 1) --->
```

---

When you perform two asynchronous call :

```
DATA (state 0) <---
DATA (state 0) <---
UPDATED DATA (state 1) --->
UPDATED DATA (state 1') ---> ERROR
```

---

It returns an error because the state of the data changed. This is how transactions are supposed to work.

---

---

To avoid the access conflict you can implement a custom queue system. Or catch the error and re-run the transaction with a setTimeout with a maximum number of try.

**Queue system** :

```
DATA (state 0) <---
UPDATED DATA (state 1) --->
DATA (state 1) <---
UPDATED DATA (state 2) --->
```

**Re-run system**

```
DATA (state 0) <---
DATA (state 0) <---
UPDATED DATA (state 1) --->
UPDATED DATA (state 1') ---> ERROR
DATA (state 1) <---
UPDATED DATA (state 2) --->
```

Comment: What's the solution?

Comment: What's the solution?

Comment: Soluce A : Create your own queue system, example using [this](https://www.npmjs.com/package/await-semaphore) and collection names.

Comment: Soluce B : Catch the transaction error and re-run your whole update.

Answer (score 0):

Do this in success and failure

```
session.endSession()
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).